# Monolithic Contrib for Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

https://github.com/clojure/clojure-contrib This link of clojure asks to use `Monolithic Contrib` with `clojure 1.3`. From where can i get jar of `Monolithic Contrib` or jar is same as `clojure-contrib`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Monolithic contrib was discontinued in Clojure 1.3, last available version is for 1.2. For 1.3 you need to use separate contrib libraries, as they listed on [Clojure Contrib page](http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Clojure+Contrib).

Splitting of contrib into separate libraries allows to develop them without additional dependencies on each other...

Comment: This is not entirely true -- the page http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go on Clojure's dev wiki mentions an unofficial build of monolithic contrib that is supposed to work with 1.3.